# Yii2 AppAsset creation issue

Tags: jquery, yii2, composer-php, assets

I have deployed a Yii2 advanced application to our test Ubuntu environment on AWS which is working fine. I've now deployed the same application to our staging environment but when I load a page from this server it fails to load `/assets/be19333e/jquery.js` due to 404.

I have checked the file and directory permissions to be sure they're correct and found that path `/assets/be19333e` has been created but not the files within.

I globally installed composer-asset-plugin

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1"
```

Why would the jQuery file not be created? How can I debug this?

Comment: there might be created into another folder

Comment: Manually clear assets folder. execute `chmod -R 777 assets`.

Comment: Are the files in the vendor folder? If so i expect the problem to be a permission-issue. Otherwise make sure the vendor-folder has the required contents either via uploading or composer.